# Spring Boot - Streaming a video with ajax call

Tags: java, html, ajax, spring-boot

I was trying to find a good tutorial on how to stream video in springboot with ajax call but I cannot find it yet.

In my app, I was stored a video file in the server, and now how can I play it in client browser with ajax call. any idea?

Thanks

Comment: why are you trying to use ajax?

Comment: I can do many thing with ajax when the video loaded

Comment: yes, i know that @Sachith. but i cannot get it tutorial yet

Comment: Could you please share code with us , without see anything how we can suppose

Comment: wait, i still looking at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this one  by following this step :
https://www.knowledgefactory.net/2019/09/spring-boot-video-streaming-example.html

mybe would be usefull for other